# MySQL объединение таблиц с группировкой с использованием count из одной таблицы

Tags: mysql, select, join, count

Добрый день! Есть одна таблица, из которой требуется вытащить данные по двум запросам. А потом объединить все это вместе. redir_num - значение, которое присутствует в обоих условиях. А вот объединение не работает :(

```
select redir_num, count(*) as "Bad" from vks where (call_result = 8 and date(dt_tm)=curdate()) group by redir_num as t1
join
select redir_num, count(*) as "Good" from vks where (call_result = 10 and date(dt_tm)=curdate()) group by redir_num as t2
on t1.redir_num=t2.redir_num;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT redir_num
     , SUM(call_result =  8 AND DATE(dt_tm)=CURDATE()) AS Bad
     , SUM(call_result = 10 AND DATE(dt_tm)=CURDATE()) AS Good
FROM vks
GROUP BY redir_num;
```

Comment: Это работает с кучей алертов почему-то "Level" "Code" "Message"
"Warning"          "1292"  "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1100+'"
"Warning"          "1292"  "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1100+'"
"Warning"          "1292"  "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1100+'"
"Warning"          "1292"  "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1100+'"

Comment: И где у Вас такое значение?

Comment: Ну, MySQL выдает такое при запуске запроса

Comment: @Пупкин_Василий А у вас поле call_result числовое ? по крайней мере это у вас единственное поле в запросе, которое проверяется и оно похоже содержит строковое значение "1100+". А если оно строка, то почему вы его сравниваете с числом ?

Comment: @Akina Кстати, а почему бы не вынести проверку даты в условие where. Что бы не пытаться суммировать по всем строкам, когда достаточно по дате. Ну и заодно переписать его так, что бы было без применения функции date к колонке (`tm_dm>=CURDATE() and tm_dm < CURDATE() + interval 1 day`)

Comment: @Mike Лениво мне сегодня что-то... да и автор не заостряет внимание на необходимости оптимизации.

Comment: @Пупкин_Василий Вы хотите сказать, что исходный запрос таких предупреждений не генерировал? странно... условие-то, единственная точка, где могли родиться такие предупреждения, скопировано один в один...

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте.
Попробуйте вот так:

```
SELECT redir_num
 , SUM(case when call_result =  8 AND DATE(dt_tm)=CURDATE() then 1 else 0 end) AS Bad
 , SUM(case when call_result = 10 AND DATE(dt_tm)=CURDATE() then 1 else 0 end) AS Good
FROM vks
GROUP BY redir_num
```

Comment: От варианта Akina ваш фактически не отличается, потому что логические операторы вроде `=` и AND в MySQL возвращают вполне себе числовые 0 или 1 и их можно суммировать, не прибегая к усложнениям воде case.

Comment: Не работает совсем :(

Comment: Можно ли это сделать именно через left join? Или не?

Comment: @Пупкин_Василий конечно не работает, там один end не дописан, в глаза же сразу бросается. или вы все копируете не глядя, авось заработает